# Two-level Cli command menu in Groovy

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface

I am working on a Groovy Cli app that supports two level commands or sub commands, similar to Kubernetes command line tool [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/). See below usage example.

```
usage: myCli [command] [command options]
commands:
command1  Command 1 description
command2  Command 2 description
help      Help on a command
version.  Show version info
```

I try [`CliBuilder`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/cli/commons/CliBuilder.html), but it does not seems to support command structure above. How can I implement this in Groovy?

Comment: PicoCLI is a popular choice nowadays

Comment: @cfrick I agree PicoCLI is probably a good choice, but it does not provide visual layout like CliBuilder does.

Comment: What do you mean by "visual layout"?

Comment: I meant I can see it exactly as in the codes. See example from `CliBuilder` [doc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/cli/commons/CliBuilder.html). Sorry, I can not copy and paste the code in comment, which has very limited formatting options.

Comment: I still don't understand what that means. If you rule out an alternative, it's fine to add this to the question (yeah, comments are not supposed to deal with this).

Comment: I didn't mean that I rule out PicoCLI. I am just stating my preference. If someone can provide a solution how this can be accomplished with PicoCLI, I will still accept it.

Comment: https://picocli.info/#_subcommands